# Change Textbox value when an item is selected in drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, select

I'm trying to change the value of a text box with the the item I select from a drop down box. But it's not working.

I tried this HTML:

```
<select name="ncontacts" id="contacts" onchange="ChooseContact(this);"> 
</select>
```

and this JS:

```
function ChooseContact(data)
{
   alert(data);
   document.getElementById("friendName").value = data;
}
```

But the text box val is not updated.

Comment: How are u passing value to ChooseContact?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because `this` (the argument to `ChooseContact`) refers to the `select` element itself, and not its value. You need to set the `value` of the `friendName` element to the `value` of the `select` element:

```
document.getElementById("friendName").value = data.value; //data is the element
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KEY9y/).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you very simple method

```js
$('#quantity').change(function(){
  var qty = $('#quantity').val();
  $("#totalprice").val(qty);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricesection">
        <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="340"/>
    Quantity: 
    <select id="quantity">
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
Total: $
<input type="text" id="totalprice" value="1"/>

    
</div>
```